# How do if(a--) and if(--a) differs by output

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, decrement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
static int a = 9;
if (a--){
   printf("after decrement a =%d\n", a);
   main();
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
after decrement a =8
after decrement a =7
after decrement a =6
after decrement a =5
after decrement a =4
after decrement a =3
after decrement a =2
after decrement a =1
after decrement a =0
```

here prints up to `a=0`

when using `if(--a)`

output:

```
after decrement a =8
after decrement a =7
after decrement a =6
after decrement a =5
after decrement a =4
after decrement a =3
after decrement a =2
after decrement a =1
```

here prints up to `a=1`

So, the question is when using `if(a--)` it prints up to `0` and when using `if(--a)` it prints up to `1`, how when using pre decrement , the output starts from `8` rather starting from `9`.

Comment: While C doesn't forbid it, it's really bad behavior to call `main` recursively. If you want to do this experiment using recursion use a separate function that you call from `main`.

Comment: As for the difference between prefix and suffix `--` (and `++` of course) that should have been explained by any decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: The difference is not in _what values get processed in a loop body_ but rathe in _when the loop terminates_. You may want to use a debugger and see step-by-step how the loop is executed. You may also try to initialize `a=1` and see what happens. And the results of setting `a=0` may be even more interesting for you...

Comment: BTW, are you sure you know why you make the `a` variable `static`...?

Answer (score 1):

This is about the post- and pre- in/decrement operators as documented at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec.

With `--a`, the `--` is executed PRIOR to returning the reference to the variable to the calculation, meaning it will basically start decremented.

With `a--`, on the other hand, the program caches the previous value of `a`, decrements it, and then returns the cached value.

So:

```
int a = 5;
printf("%d\n", --a); //Prints 4
printf("%d\n", a--); //Prints 4
printf("%d\n", a); //Prints 3
```

Comment: "This is about 'operator precedence'." No it isn't. It is about the behavior of post increment versus pre increment.

Comment: @Lundin You are, of course, correct. I amended the introductory statement.

Comment: @Lundin Actually, there are two questions in the OP. One about why the output terminates at 0 v. 1, and another about why the both outputs starts with 8, not 9... Tricky...

Answer (score 0):

OP: "how when using pre decrement , the output starts from 8 rather starting from 9"

In both cases, pre- and post- decrement, the variable is decremented in the `if( )` conditional before the value of the variable is printed in the `printf( )`.